# Reattach an Image after removeFromParent in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

attach an Image after you have called removeFromParent in GWT?

The Image was created from an UiBinder
e.g.

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Image ui:field="myImage"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>

public class Testing extends Composite {
  interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Testing> {}
  private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);
  @UiField Image myImage;
  public Testing() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }
  public void remove() {
    myImage.removeFromParent();
  }
  public void add() {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could add a field referencing your container panel:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="imgPanel">
    <g:Image ui:field="myImage"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

you could then go:

```
imgPanel.add(myImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of remove the image, you can just hide the image :

```
public void remove() {
  myImage.setVisible(false);
}
public void add() {
  myImage.setVisible(true);
}
```

Add and remove from the DOM is expensive for the browser.